# Setting a seed for each iteration in R

Tags: r, random-seed

In R, I have a code with many iterations that could potentially benefit from parallelization, but I need reproducibility. In general I use `parallel` package and `clusterSetRNGStream` function but this solution is dependent from the number of workers, that is if I use the same seed in 2 different runs, the first with 12 workers and the second one with 24 workers then I will obtain different results, furthermore in this way I cannot use load balance.

So, I thought to do the following procedure, suppose I have `n` iterations, I use the following code:

```
set.seed(1)

workersSeed = vector(length = n)

for(i in 1:n){
  workersSeed = ceiling( runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = (1e+9 * n) - 1) )
}

clusterExport(cl, "workersSeed")

clusterApplyLB(cl, x = c(1:n), fun = function(x){

  set.seed(workersSeed[x])
  
  ### do something
  
})
```

So in this way I will set the seed for each iteration and it will not depend from the number of workers, since the seeds are i.i.d. Discrete Uniform distributed on {1, 2, ..., n*10^9} I think there will not be problems with the pseudo RNG.

Is it correct? Can I use this procedure safely?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: just set the seed once. Not on every iteration. Setting a seed once still makes the work reproducible

Comment: @onyambu it's more complicated than that when running in parallel.

Comment: I would use `multidplyr` for this instead. If you structure your data as `tibble` you can add a columns of seeds. Then use `map2(data, seed, ...)` and start your function with `set.seed`.

Comment: To add to my comment: the main issue with your approach is that you cannot have dynamic inputs to your function (your input is now `x` to index the seed vector).  This can be easily avoided using `map`, `map2`, or `pmap` from the `purrr` package and using `multidplyr` (or the `furrr`+`future` combo if preferred).

Answer (score 1):

This would be one approach with `multidplyr` (could also be done with `cluster_call` to avoid `dplyr`'s `mutate`).

### Here is a simple MWE using `mutate`:

```r
set.seed(1)
library(multidplyr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(purrr)


n = 10
workersSeed = vector(length = n)

for(i in 1:n){
  workersSeed[i] = ceiling( runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = (1e+6 * n) - 1) )
}
workersSeed <- as.integer(workersSeed)

cl <- new_cluster(2)

f <- function(x,seed){
  set.seed(seed)
  runif(x)
}

cl <- cluster_assign(cl, 'f' = f)
cl <- cluster_library(cl, c('dplyr', 'purrr'))

tib <- tibble(
  x = 5,
  seed = workersSeed
) %>% 
  partition(cl)

tib %>% 
  mutate(
    rnd = map2(x, seed, f)
  ) %>% 
  collect()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>        x    seed rnd      
#>    <dbl>   <int> <list>   
#>  1     5 2655087 <dbl [5]>
#>  2     5 5728534 <dbl [5]>
#>  3     5 2016820 <dbl [5]>
#>  4     5 9446752 <dbl [5]>
#>  5     5 6291140 <dbl [5]>
#>  6     5 3721239 <dbl [5]>
#>  7     5 9082077 <dbl [5]>
#>  8     5 8983896 <dbl [5]>
#>  9     5 6607978 <dbl [5]>
#> 10     5  617863 <dbl [5]>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Here is MWE using `cluster_call`:

```r
set.seed(1)
library(multidplyr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(purrr)

n = 10
workersSeed = list()
x = list()
for(i in 1:n){
  workersSeed[[i]] = as.integer( runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = (1e+6 * n) - 1) )
  x[[i]] = as.integer( runif(n = 1, min = 1, 5) )
}

f <- function(x,seed){
  set.seed(seed)
  runif(x)
}

cl <- new_cluster(2)
cl <- cluster_assign(cl, 'f' = f)
cl <- cluster_assign_partition(cl, 'x' = x)
cl <- cluster_assign_partition(cl, 'workersSeed' = workersSeed)
cl <- cluster_library(cl, 'purrr')

cluster_call(cl, map2(x, workersSeed, f))
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 0.5772564 0.8304574
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 0.5645438 0.3818428 0.8860517 0.1140823
#> 
#> [[1]][[3]]
#> [1] 0.28959061 0.66412397 0.05804375 0.39163171
#> 
#> [[1]][[4]]
#> [1] 0.4380956 0.1642390 0.2337461
#> 
#> [[1]][[5]]
#> [1] 0.413938
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 0.6696015
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] 0.8529555 0.7387618
#> 
#> [[2]][[3]]
#> [1] 0.4511827 0.7996660
#> 
#> [[2]][[4]]
#> [1] 0.53140238 0.55989017 0.01163488 0.16865397
#> 
#> [[2]][[5]]
#> [1] 0.9555809 0.0923941 0.8269986 0.6047000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>